# My F# code doesn't run, how can I investigate further?

Tags: visual-studio, f#

I downloaded Visual Studio Community 2015 to try and lean F#. My F# projects compiles without any issues but when I try to launch the console project (even the default console project) Visual Studio just hangs and then freezes. The only way I have to shut it down is to go to the task manager.

Same thing if I try to directly launch the generated .exe file: explorer freezes and I have to go to the task manager to restart it.

All my C# projects work fine...

Comment: Which version of VS?

Comment: The 2015 version of VS Community (I'll edit my post to add that)

Comment: Can you step into it using F11? There might be a bug in your app causing it to hang.

Comment: No as I mentioned it occurs even with the default F# console project (or the F# tutorial). Same behavior with F11, my program doesn't even start, VS just freezes

Comment: Not sure what can be done, I suppose a vs repair or reinstall, might work, but I'm out of ideas

Comment: I already tried the repair ... I'm good to pick another functional language I guess !

Comment: Do you have any anti-virus installed? I've seen this behavior before and disabling anti-virus helped :-). Also, try running the code without debugger (`Ctrl+F5`) or run it using F# Interactive.

Comment: I was the anti-virus indeed ! It deactivated it to test and now everything works fine. Thanks

Comment: I was my first question on stackoverflow, how am I suppose to flag this questions as resolved and indicate that your comment was the answer ?

Comment: Let me extend my answer from a comment into a proper answer - then you can mark it as accepted. Glad we figured it out :) not being able to run your code is very frustrating!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have seen a similar behavior before on a machine that had an anti-virus installed. The anti-virus was blocking Visual Studio from running F# code with debugger and disabling the anti-virus resolved the issue.

In general, there are a few ways to run F# code in Visual Studio:

- Using <kbd>F5</kbd> to start the program with a debugger (this is the one that the anti-virus was blocking); <kbd>F11</kbd> which steps into the debugger was also not working
- Using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> which starts the program *without* a debugger - this should work!
- By creating an F# script file (`Script.fsx`), selecting code and using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to run code using F# interactive - this should work too.

Many people do quite a lot of work with F# using F# Interactive, so learning how to use that is a good skill, but to use the debugger, disabling anti-virus should do the trick.